# php использование переменных внутри class

Tags: php, классы

Как использовать переменные внутри класса? ВОт пример кода, который нужно заставить работать:

```
class config
{
  public $a = "test";
  public $b = $a."/1";
  public $c = $a."/2";
}
```

Comment: почитайте про `$this`, `self` и `static`

Comment: Если лень читать материалы из рекомендованного выше - то запомните хотя бы одно. Это не переменные внутри класса, а свойства класса. Их нельзя использовать как простые переменные

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы один параметр использовал значение другого. Вместо того, чтобы тыкать документацией помогли бы сразу решить задачу.

Comment: Мог бы уже сам разобраться, тут нет никакой задачи даже

Comment: Уже сделал, но такие умники прям бесят.

Answer (score 0):

Через `constant`

```
class config
{
    const a = "test";
    public $b = self::a."/1";
}

$a = new config;
var_dump($a);
```

Проблема в том, что так как вы делаете - не правильно логически, потому что в момент инициализации `$b` класс не знает еще о существовании `$a`, надо скорей в конструкторе такие манипуляции проводить:

```
class config
{
    public $conf = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->conf['a'] = 'test';
        $this->conf['b'] = $this->conf['a']."/1";
        $this->conf['c'] = $this->conf['a']."/1";
    }
}

$a = new config;
var_dump($a);
```

Если вам все-таки нужны переменные `$a`, `$b` и `$c`, то в том-же ключе:

```
class config
{
    public $a, $b, $c;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->a = 'test';
        $this->b = $this->a."/1";
        $this->c = $this->a."/2";
    }
}
```